# How to use passport-local to authenticate in composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to use [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) to authenticate user to login into composer rest server like other passport strategies ( e.g `passport-github`,`passport-google`).

So first I try to set `COMPOSER_PROVIDER` variable like this

```
"local": {
    "provider": "local",
    "module": "passport-local",
    "usernameField": "username",
    "passwordField": "password",
    "authPath": "/auth/local",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect": "/"}
```

Then i run the server in docker (with mongo as persisted datasource) and add some user in database collection

The question is what's next step that i need to use this passport.Because i run this command and still get response with `401 Unauthorized`

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
>   '{"username":"{USER_NAME}","password":"{USER_PASSWORD}"}'
>   http://localhost:3000/auth/local

Is it not enough to use this passport? Does i need to start another service to locally authenticate this login (e.g. GitHub oAuth Application )?

Comment: Have you got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to customize your composer-rest-server, based on the loopback framework, according to your requirements.

I suggest to read this tutorial from the official documentation.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/customizing-the-rest-server

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to do that also initially, but then I just edit the server.js file on the composer rest server for basic auth at the end.

1. check where your composer-rest-server is stored

> npm root -g

2. Open where server.js is located

> ```
> cd /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server
> ```

3. Add this to the code

> ```
> const basicauth = require('basicauth-middleware');
> app.use(basicauth('username', 'password!');
> ```

Comment: Basic un-hashed authentication is different from a local passport strategy.