# Hyperledger Composer - Rest Server Local Passport Strategy

Tags: passport.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm trying to implement the ***Local Passport Strategy for Hyperledger Composer Rest Server***. 
Instead of using a third part service to authenticate the users (in the official example is used GitHub Oauth https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication)
i would retrieve the data directly from a local db.
Does anyone any advice about the architecture and configuration to adopt in order to achive this?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Did you get this working using `passport-local` strategy?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer supports the passport strategies at http://www.passportjs.org/packages/

See this Stack overflow -> [How to use passport-local to authenticate in composer rest server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216970/how-to-use-passport-local-to-authenticate-in-composer-rest-server?rq=1) but its `COMPOSER_PROVIDERS`  not `COMPOSER_PROVIDER` fyi.

Not tried this but something like this for COMPOSER_PROVIDERS:

`"local": { 
    "provider": "local", 
    "module": "passport-local", 
    "usernameField": "username", 
    "passwordField": "password", 
    "authPath": "/auth/local", 
    "callbackURL":"/auth/local/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/", 
    "failureRedirect": "/", 
    "setAccessToken": true, 
    "callbackHTTPMethod": "post" 
   },`

hope this helps.