# Plugging in basic authentication instead of OAuth in Passport in composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to plug in basic authentication with Passport that involves username and password [would secure using HTTPS later] rather than using OAUTH  in Composer-Rest-Server?

Do I need to add a middleware between composer-rest-server and the client that stores usernames and passwords and then routes to appropriate URIs on Composer-Rest-Server or is it just possible using Composer-Rest-Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Composer REST server supports strategies per http://www.passportjs.org/packages/

Someone has provided an answer here that may help you with a sample COMPOSER_PROVIDERS for passport-local -> [How to use passport-local to authenticate in composer rest server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216970/how-to-use-passport-local-to-authenticate-in-composer-rest-server/49442266#49442266)

On the Composer docs site, there are only examples of using two strategies presently: Github (OAUTH2) and Google OAUTH2.